# Wordpress ACF exclude private post from relationship loop

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, advanced-custom-fields

I have a post relationship option in ACF in woocommerce products. Some products are marked as private. I am able to select published and private products and display it as below.

How to exclude private posts from loop below?

```
while ( have_rows( 'similar_product' ) ) {the_row();
```

```
            $products = get_sub_field( 'select_product' ); ?>
            <?php if ( $products !== false ) { ?>
                <a href="<?php echo get_the_permalink( $products->ID ) ?>">
                    <?php echo get_the_post_thumbnail( $products->ID, 'medium', ); ?>
                </a>
            <?php }
        }
        echo "</div>";
        ?>
    </div>
<?php } ?>
```

I tried to exclude private post from select option in ACF but I need this possibility in case when related product will be available again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The post's visibility is set in it's `post_status` property. Checking `'private' === $products->post_status` will indicate if a post is private. Recommend to use [`get_post_status()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_post_status/) helper function.

To only display published products, try this (untested):

```php
if ( false !== $products && 'publish' === get_post_status( $products) ) {
```

You could also skip private posts, if you prefer that approach:

```php
if ( false === $products || 'private' === get_post_status( $products ) ) {
    continue;
}
```